# Is this reasoning about convergence correct?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I was wondering if my reasoning made any sense (please see the pictures). Thank you very much in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Why did you write that $$x^{2n}-x^n=\sqrt{x^n(x^n-1)}\;??$$ This is highly untrue in the general case, of course. This is like writing that $\;a=\sqrt a\;$ ...! And either you refer to some specific value(s) of $\;x\;$ , or if you're not given that you can divide in cases. Finally, the comparison test es appliable **to positive series**, not just any series.

Comment: @donantonio How are you?  It's good to see you're still here.  And your comment is spot on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I indeed have no clue why I said that, that's a huge mistake.. The thing I wonder though is that my teacher told me to say that:

x^2n - x^n = x^n(x^n-1) 

However, I cannot seem to find what to do with his hint, because as far as I can remember he also told me, to state:

x^2n - x^n = x^n(x^n-1)  =< sqrt(x^n*x^n) and then use the root test?

Comment: I can't tell what the aim of the first question is precisely.

Comment: @MathNoob123 Are you assuming $\;x>0\;$?

Comment: Do you understand the reason that the series comverges for $-1<x<1$?  Now, check the cases for which $x=1$, $x=-1$ separately.  Apply the root test for $|x|>1$.